# Change button's action dynamically

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-view

Can a button's action be changed dynamically depending on another field's value? Example code:

```
<xpath expr="//button[@class='oe_stat_button o_res_partner_tip_opp']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="name">%(action1)d</attribute>
    <attribute name="name">%(action2)d</attribute>
</xpath>
```

That button's action would be action1 or action2 depending on, let's say, a boolean/select/whatever field's value. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are at least two possibilities:

**Create multiple buttons and show or hide them by condition**

In the end it should look like:

```xml
<field name="my_selection_field" />
<button name="%(action1)d" string="Action 1" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_selection_field', '!=', 'selection1')]}" />
<button name="%(action2)d" string="Action 2" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_selection_field', '!=', 'selection2')]}" />
<button name="%(action3)d" string="Action 3" attrs="{'invisible': [('my_selection_field', '!=', 'selection3')]}" />
```

It's obviously not the perfect solution, but it should work.

**Use a python method returning an action**

That will work, too, but will be a bit more dynamic. Just make the button of type `object` and set a model multi record method in the `name` attribute.

```xml
<button action="button_dynamic_action" string="Action" type="object" />
```

And now implement that method on the views model:

```py
@api.multi
def button_dynamic_action(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    action = {}
    if self.my_selection_field == 'selection1':
        action = {
            'name': _('Action 1'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'my.model',
            #'view_id': # optional
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            #'res_id': # optional
            'target': 'new' # or 'current'
        }
    elif self.my_selection_field == 'selection2':
        action = {
            'name': _('Action 2'),
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree',
            'res_model': 'my.model',
            #'view_id': # optional
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            #'res_id': # optional
            'target': 'current' # or 'new'
        }
    # and so on
    return action
```

You can also read from already existing window actions (ir.actions.act_window) instead of "creating" them in code, following example is from Odoo itself:

```py
res = self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id('base', 'action_attachment')
# ... change res with context or name and so on
return res
```

Comment: First method didn't work, buttons duplicated themselves with the last one's configuration, don't know why. But your second method worked for me. In the model function, just return **self.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id('my_module', 'my_action')** depending on the other field value. I didn't know that function. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There were some mistakes in the first possible solution, i've fixed them now.

Comment: Perfect answer Nothing to add